How do I define a .properties file for a resource pack item?
I’m trying to create a resource pack for Hypixel Skyblock; a game I really enjoy playing. However, I’m struggling with how to get it working, especially when it comes to creating a .properties file for items in version 1.8.9. Could you please provide an example and any additional details or guidance? I’m not very familiar with this process, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
Please and Thank you!
P.S. I found an article on this website that answered my question, but I can’t seem to find it again. Unfortunately, I didn’t have an account at the time.


You don't.
.properties isn't a thing in data packs; the information you've found is probably wrong or out of date, or is for a mod.
Have a look at this tutorial. (Bedrock)
Edit: The .properties file appears to be an Optifine-specific feature. The documentation mentions it here

Really? Please explain, because I’ve seen many other resource packs with this format using both .json and .properties files. The .json file contains the model, and the .properties file provides the model’s details. At least, that’s how I understand it. If you don’t believe me, you can download a resource pack and look through it using 7-Zip or WinRAR.

I’m trying to make it from scratch, and I’m going to add more stuff into the resource pack for Hypixel Skyblock.

Do I look retarded with this question I posted?

@Kenzudo If you could post the website that you mention that somewhat explains what you're looking for that might help, but in the whole time I've worked with data and resource packs, I haven't seen a .properties file. I'm not a psychic you know?

Upon further research, the .properties file for any given item/entity/block is an Optifine-specific feature.

ig that how you put it Yes it .properties for Optifine

Use this https://optifine.readthedocs.io/cit.html?h=propert to understand the format. Then, use another resource pack that follows similar rules as yours and copy their format like in the .properties file.

Hi Kenzudo, thanks for writing out an answer to your own question, but can you please add some punctuation and perhaps some additional information? As it is, it's hard to tell exactly how this answers your question.

So sorry, im going change it now

Do you think you could put an example of that in your answer? "use another resource pack that follows similar rules as yours" might be lost if those resource packs are somehow deleted off the internet.

I don’t know. I’m self-teaching myself this, so I don’t really know. That’s why I asked here and waited for a week but didn’t get any response. So, I just thought of an idea.
